# why module Qt5Quick.dll sometimes generate error and application crash because of it?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

i have an application that run properly good but sometimes it crash and because i am away i can't see what happened exactly,just i can check event viewer of Windows that it return this

## error:

**Faulting application name:**
myApp.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5c35ee78

**Faulting module name:**
 Qt5Quick.dll, version: 5.9.1.0, time stamp: 0x59539656

**Exception code:**
 0xc0000005

**Fault offset:**
0x0009c690

**Faulting process id:**
 0xea4

**Faulting application start time:**
 0x01d4b1a8a0ea5d8b

**Faulting application path:**
 C:\Program Files\myApp.exe

**Faulting module path:**
C:\Program Files\Qt5Quick.dll

**Report Id:**
 1c079607-b5f9-4991-b144-ccea521260e3

**Faulting package full name:**

**Faulting package-relative application ID:**

event ID=1000 and Task category is 100 --------
it's so strange that in some system this error occur more and in some of them 1 time in day.i search a lot about this error but nothing found.is there any body know what i get this error?

**ps:**
Qt 5.9.1 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit)
if need more detail say me.thanks

Comment: The exception code means an access violation. It's probably a good idea to add quite some logging if you're not able to sit and watch ;-)

Comment: yes i think i should do it